# Выполнение кода при загрузке определенного блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Всем привет, вот уже почти целый день мучаюсь таким вот решение

Есть галерея в Wordpress PrettyPhoto, она формирует блок с картинками и в зависимости от ширины экрана укладывает их в один или больше рядов. Для того чтоб я поместил их по центру мне нужно знать ширину первого ряда блоку, для этого я беру только те блоки у которых `top:0px;` их количество умножаю на 351 (ширина блока с картинкой + 1px) и передаю этот параметр в ширину главного блоку.

Загвоздка заключается в том, что если на странице есть большое количество картинок, сам скрипт не запускается пока все картинки не будут загружены, но по окончанию загрузки возникает "прыжок" от левой стороны браузера, блоки центрируются (согласно margin: 0 auto;).

я думал о решении таким что скрипт должен запускаться уже после загрузки первого ряда (у которых `top:0px;`), но как его реализовать не знаю.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```js
(function($){
  function imgWidthBl(){
    var top_bl = $(".wpb_gallery_slider li.isotope-item").filter(function(){
     return $(this).css("top")== "0px";
    });
    $(".wpb_gallery_slider .wpb_image_grid_ul").css("width", function(){
      var wH = top.length * 351;
       return wH
    });
  };

$(window).load(function(){
  imgWidthBl();
});

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.wpb_image_grid_ul .isotope-item{
 margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
 max-width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
.wpb_image_grid_ul {
margin:0 auto;
}
.wpb_image_grid_ul a {
 width:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_gallery_slides wpb_image_grid" data-interval="3">
 <ul class="wpb_image_grid_ul" style="position: relative; height: 4518px;">
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
   <a class="prettyphoto" href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[slideshow]">
    <img class="" src="img1.jpg" width="350" height="250" ">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 351px; top: 0px;">
   <a class="prettyphoto" href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[slideshow]">
    <img class="" src="img1.jpg" width="350" height="250" ">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 702px; top: 0px;">
   <a class="prettyphoto" href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[slideshow]">
    <img class="" src="img1.jpg" width="350" height="250" ">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 251px;">
   <a class="prettyphoto" href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[slideshow]">
    <img class="" src="img1.jpg" width="350" height="250" ">
   </a>
  </li>
    <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 351px; top: 251px;">
   <a class="prettyphoto" href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[slideshow]">
    <img class="" src="img1.jpg" width="350" height="250" ">
   </a>
  </li>
    <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 702px; top: 251px;">
   <a class="prettyphoto" href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[slideshow]">
    <img class="" src="img1.jpg" width="350" height="250" ">
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, работать не будет от слова совсем. У isotope есть свои функции, через которые можно настраивать вывод. Посмотрите документацию https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо нашол в документациях. isFitWidth если кому то надо будет.